# Python Kivy Android

Tags: android, python, kivy

Recently I have created a dummy android app using Python2 and Kivy. Binded it using buildozer but when I installed it on my android device everything going good so far but app is not loading the screen. It opens and instantly closed it, and no error(s) displayed :(

I am using kivy 1.11.0 and buildozer version is 0.34. Application is working before binding it to .apk

## Python Code

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')
#from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class screen1(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="hello world!"))
        self.add_widget(Label(text="bye world!"))


class SampleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SampleKivy().run()
```

Comment: There is a typo, `Ladel` should be 'Label`.

Comment: @Juna: Please share your buildozer.spec

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B2VtpACXaTRzWvMX_-dUOrAAcM21hkCN

Comment: @Juna: The latest Kivy nightly version is 1.11.0-dev0. Edit your `buildozer.spec` and replace `osx.kivy_version = 1.11.1` with `osx.kivy_version = 1.10.0`

Comment: ok sir and should i install kivy 1.10??

Comment: and we only need to .apk file into our phone or whole project folder?

Comment: You can install 'Android Studio' on your computer, then connect your `Android` device to the computer via `USB`. 'Android Studio` will allow you to see `system` messages from your `Android` device when you run your app.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04lts.. because buildzore os requirment